# Hartshorne Proposition 4.3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following proof on page 25 of AG.

Let $Y$ to be a quasi-affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$, with $p\in Y$. Define $Z = \overline{Y} - Y$, this is a closed set in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Form the ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq k[x_1,...,x_n]$ corresponding to $Z$. Choose a polynomial $f$such that $f \in \mathfrak{a}$ but $f(p) \not = 0$. Define $H$ to be the hypersurface of $f$. Hartshorne says (i) $Y - (Y\cap H)$ is a closed subset of $(\mathbb{A}^n - H)$ and (ii) therefore $Y-(Y\cap H)$ is affine since $(\mathbb{A}^n - H)$ is affine.

Where is (i) coming from? And how does (ii) follow, a closed subset of an affine set is not necessarily affine, is it?

Answer (score 4):

(i) Check that $Y - H = \overline{Y} \cap (\mathbb{A}^n - H)$. Note that $H$ contains $Z$.

(ii) Closed subsets of closed subsets are closed! Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Of course, when we say that $\mathbb{A}^n - H$ is affine we mean that it's isomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$.

Comment: For number (i), I agree that $Y-H = \overline{Y}\cap (\mathbb{A}^n - H)$ but why does it follow that $Y-(Y-H)$ is closed in the complement of $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: I think I'm just using the definition of the subspace topology: I wrote the set as the intersection of a closed subset in the ambient space with the subspace. Where does $Y - (Y - H) = Y \cap H$ enter?

Comment: I understand everything you are writing I just do not see the conclusion. I know that the $Y-H$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n-H$ because it is written as an intersection of a closed set in the ambient space. I see that $Y - (Y-H) = Y\cap H$, and so $Y-(Y-H)$ is closed in $Y$. But I do not see how this implies that $Y-(Y-H)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n - H$.

Comment: I thought all we wanted was for $Y - (Y \cap H)$ [which is the same as $Y - H$; I just didn't want to type more characters] to be closed in $\mathbb{A}^n - H$.

Comment: Thank you mr Hoot. I apologize for any confusion. For some reason, entirely beyond me, I spend like an hour trying to prove that $Y-(Y-H)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n - H$. But the actual statement was $Y - (Y\cap H)$.

Comment: For part (ii). I still do not understand. Hartshorne says that an "affine variety" is any variety which is isomorphic to an affine one. Why does an isomorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n - H$ with an affine variety carry its closed subsets to affine varieties? What about the irreducibility condition on the topological space (a closed subset of an irreducible space is not necessarily irreducible).

Comment: An isomorphism is in particular a homeomorphism, so I hope closedness is clear. I'm not sure that irreducibility is important here, but $Y - H$ is a non-empty open subset of the irreducible space $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, I now fully understand the proof. 

Separate question. Is it acceptable to talk about morphisms between arbitrary sets (not affine, not irreducible)? Or is the concept of morphisms only restricted to the category of quasi-varieties?